# How to copy a map in golang?

Tags: dictionary, go, syntax

I can offer decomposition of map to 2 slices example:

```
func decomposeMap(m map[string]int) ([]string, []int) {
  var i uint
  l := len(m)
  keys, values := make([]string, l), make([]int, l)
  for keys[i], values[i] = range m {
    i++
  }
  return keys, values
}
```

but I am failing to write map copying:

```
func copyMap(m map[string]int) map[string]int {
  m2 := make(map[string]int, len(m))
  for id, m2[id] = range m {} // error - id is not declared
  for id, m2[id] := range m {} // error with m2[id] already declared
  // id should not be accessible here, it should exist only inside loop
  return m2
}
```

I can declare id as a var, but I dont want it to be available outside for loop. How can i mix assigment and declaration, eg: `for id:=, m[id]= range m {}` ?
So it will declare index just inside for loop, and will be not accessible outside?

Comment: To iterate over the entries of a map, you simply do `for k, v := range m {}`. `v` will be the value associated with `k` key. The `for` loop makes the lookup, not you. Or if you want to, you may do `for k := range m { v := m[k] }`

Comment: So to copy the map, the loop should be: `for k, v := range m { m2[k] = v }`

Comment: @icza i dont need to iterate, i need to copy. and i need to avoid repeated assigments. you want to first assign m's value to v, and then 2nd assign v to m2. I want to avoid that

Comment: @icza You are doing dual job: `v := m[k]` and then `m2[k] = v`. if this `v` is a struct it will be copied over twice. 1) from map `m` to temp buffer `v`, and then 2) from temp buffer `v` to second map `m2`. I want to avoid that. example `var id string; for id, m2[id] = range m {}` but here id is declared outside for loop and will remain afterwards you run the loop

Comment: OK, I see what you want. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `id` variable must be declared before `for`, because you can't use short variable declaration with `m2[id]`.

```
func copyMap(m map[string]int) map[string]int {
    m2 := make(map[string]int, len(m))
    var id string
    for id, m2[id] = range m {
    }
    return m2
}
```

**But! This won't duplicate the map!** The key is only assigned to `id` after `m2[id]` is already evaluated, so this loop will assign values to keys of the previous iteration, this is not duplicating, this is "shuffling"!

This is basically a tuple assignment (key and value are assigned to `id, m2[id]`). [Spec: Assignments:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignments)

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of [index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [pointer indirections](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators) (including implicit pointer indirections in [selectors](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors)) on the left and the expressions on the right are all [evaluated in the usual order](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation). Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

So first `id` and `m2[id]` are evaluated (including the index expression), so `id` is not "yet" changed, so the value from the previous iteration is used, and only after this are the new key and values assigned.

To demonstrate, see:

```
m := map[string]int{
    "one":   1,
    "two":   2,
    "three": 3,
}
m2 := copyMap(m)
fmt.Println(m2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kgkfunoTf3_6)):

```
map[:1 one:2 two:3]
```

The values are assigned to different keys (different than in the source map), and one value is assigned to the empty string key in the first iteration (the default, zero value of `id`).

To duplicate the map, simply use:

```
for id, v := range m {
    m2[id] = v
}
```

Or if you want to avoid the temporary assignment:

```
for id := range m {
    m2[id] = m[id]
}
```

Comment: I beleive last `for id := range m {` is inefficient, because it seems `for id, v := range m` gets `v` for cheap just during iteration of map, and `m2[id] = m[id]` can only get value with having additional lookup call, additionally to having iteration over it..